# ruby code is showing as html in template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I have a rails app which uses angularjs. Here I'm trying to render a template from rails controller and pass a resource to the template. But the ruby code for displaying the variables are showing exactly as it is in the html.erb view.

```
def fail
    @order = Order.find(1)
    render 'payments/fail'
end
```

in view

```
<%= @order.as_json %>
```

Comment: Is that the entire contents of `payments/_fail.html.erb`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the problem is in the name of your view file.  I'd guess that you named it something like `fail.html` instead of `fail.html.erb`.  Without the .erb suffix, Rails just interprets the file as html text and renders it without interpreting the ruby code.

However, changing the file name isn't quite the correct solution.  Since you want to render json instead of HTML you don't need to create a view template, so you should just delete the template file altogether.

All Rails models have an .as_json method automatically, so you can simply modify your controller's fail method like so:

```
def fail
  @order = Order.find(1)
  render json: @order.as_json
end
```

Also if you want to do something fancy and modify the json that is returned, you can define your own `as_json` method inside the model.

Comment: i want the template, not just the object.

Comment: So... was I correct about the misnaming of the template file?

Comment: This outputs "<%= @order.as_json %>" in a browser?